# How to Implement Cross-Validation with Large Datasets in TensorFlow without Loading Entire Dataset into Memory?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, cross-validation, tf.data.dataset

I'm currently working with a large dataset for a machine learning project and have chosen to use TensorFlow's tf.data API to efficiently manage data loading and preprocessing without loading the entire dataset into memory. This approach has worked well for my initial training.

However I have difficulties to  implement cross-validation. From my understanding, TensorFlow does not natively support cross-validation directly through the tf.data API, and integrating with Keras for cross-validation seems to require loading data in memory first. This is problematic for my use, as loading the entire dataset into memory at once goes against the purpose of using tf.data.

I'm looking for a workaround or a method to implement cross-validation that is compatible with TensorFlow's on-demand data loading. Ideally, I'd like to maintain the memory efficiency of tf.data while having cross-validation for my model's evaluation.

Is there a way to use cross-validation with Keras or any other library that doesn't require me loading all the dataset into memory?